# Debugging a driver with WinDbg - How set a breakpoint at DriverEntry?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, kernel, wdm

I have a driver which is, for some unknown reasons causing a bugcheck 0x0000003b.

So I decided to set up a Hyper-V VM and use kernel debugging to see what exactly is going on. I already enable testing signing with **bcdedit**, and checked that the driver is indeed loaded and running with **sc query**. The problem is that I want WinDbg to step in ONLY when the offending driver is being called and not when the windows debugee is booting,  how can I do that?
How do I instruct windbg to pause at the DriverEntry function of my driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint at DriverEntry using command 'bm DriverName!DriverEntry'.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answer, it should be pointed out that if you don't have symbols for your driver, you won't be able to use the `module!DriverEntry` notation to break on `DriverEntry`.

Instead you can use:

```
sxe ld module
```

([source](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8671/245))

To break when `module` gets loaded. As usual you can leave out the `.sys` extension and only use the base name.

(Side-note: this doesn't seem to work for UM modules, such as DLLs being loaded.)